# Setting up a usb HP printer on Linux Mint 19.3

Tags: linux-mint, hplip, hp-printer

I am dual booting my Windows 10 laptop and I chose the Linux Mint 19.3 distro to run alongside windows with the dual boot option. When I boot into Linux I'm not having any success connecting to my USB printer which is a LaserJet M1212nf MFP and that printer is supported by HP.

I've got hplip 3.17.10 and hplip-gui 3.17.10 installed and I also ran hp-plugin to install the plugin.  When I run hp-setup from the command line I select USB on page one and then when I click on Next I get a "No devices found" message. Just for good measure I plugged in my usb printer before running hp-setup.

Update: I've tried running hplip.3.20.5.run and I'm getting this message:

Following dependencies are not installed. HPLIP will not work if all REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some of the HPLIP features will not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not installed.
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional
xsane                scan                 OPTIONAL
python3-notify2      gui_qt5              OPTIONAL
python3-pyqt4-dbus   gui_qt4              OPTIONAL
python3-pyqt4        gui_qt4              REQUIRED
python3-pyqt5-dbus   gui_qt5              OPTIONAL
python3-pyqt5        gui_qt5              REQUIRED
python3-dbus         fax                  REQUIRED
python3-reportlab    fax                  OPTIONAL
Do you want to install these missing dependencies (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y

### INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES

note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: python3-pyqt4 (PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))
warning: This installer cannot install 'python3-pyqt4' for your distro/OS and/or version.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency. Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.

I checked to see if I have python3-pyqt4 installed and it looks like I do:

(base) david@david-Inspiron-3520:~/Downloads$ dpkg -l | grep python3-pyqt4
ii  python3-pyqt4                              4.12.1+dfsg-2                                    amd64        Python3 bindings for Qt4

Please let me know your thoughts!

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

Recommend taking a look at the HP community web site. If you search for
`HPLIP 3.19.12 (Linux Mint 19.3): Plugin installation failed`
& scroll down to Problem solved, there is a list of commands which may help resolve your issue.

Also worth noting for future reference that before installing new version of `hplip`, hp recommend removing any older versions of `hplip` related packages to avoid possible conflicts with the new version.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge hplip hplip-data hplip-doc hplip-gui hpijs-ppds \
libsane-hpaio printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/share/hplip/
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Thanks, annahri. I get the error message "warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: python3-pyqt4 (PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))." But when I execute the command "dpkg -l | grep python3-pyqt4"  I see that python3-pyqt4 is installed. Also,  HPLIP 3.19.12 is for Linux Mint 19.2 (Tessa) and there is no option during the install for Linux Mint 19.3 (Tricia). Thanks!